# After creating Custom post type by user delete old one

Tags: custom-post-types, php, url-rewriting, wp-delete-post

I have created a form where users update their profile. When a profile is created or updated it creates a CPT called course. The url is `the permalink + /course/ + the title of the course`

```
/*  CREATING COURSE PAGES FROM USER PROFILES */

function create_course_page( $user_id = '' ) {
   $user = new WP_User($user_id);
   if ( ! $user->ID ) return '';

   // check if the user whose profile is updating has already a post
   global $wpdb;
   $course_post_exists = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
   "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type = 'course' and post_status = 'publish'", $user->course_name
   ) );

  if ( ! in_array('instructor', $user->roles) ) return '';

  $user_info = array_map( function( $a ){ return $a[0]; }, get_user_meta( $user->ID ) );
  $title = $user_info['course_name'];
  // of course create the content as you want
  $content = 'This is the page for: ';
  $content .= $user_info['description_course'];
  $post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_name' => $user->course_name,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'course'
  );
  if ( $course_post_exists ) {
    $post['ID'] = $course_post_exists;
    wp_update_post( $post );
  } else {
    wp_insert_post( $post );
  }
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'create_course_page' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'create_course_page' );
```

The problem that I'm facing is that when someone changes the title of the course it creates a new post with this url.

So I want to delete the old post when a title change is done on the course.

NOTE: When changing title of the course it changes the URL, that is why I think it takes like a new post.

I have customised this code a bit to do the job:

```
/* REMOVE OLD COURSES WHEN UPDATE */
add_action( 'admin_init', 'removing_older_posts' );
function removing_older_posts() {
    $args = array (
        'post_type'         => 'course',
        'author'            => get_current_user_id(),
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { //if the current user has posts under his/her name
        $i = 0; //create post counter
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) { //loop through each post
            $query->the_post(); //get the current post
            if ($i > 0) { //if you're not on the first post
                wp_delete_post( $query->post->ID, true ); //delete the post
            }
            $i++; //increment the post counter
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

But it isn't working.

Appreciate any suggestion :)

Comment: Have you considered just updating the title instead so that no new course post is created?

Comment: Thanks for your response. We'll, that would be a solution... But don't know how  Because hen the title updates. It changes the url.

Comment: why do you create a post based off of a user meta value? would it not be easier to create a course post then set its author to the user?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Really appreciate. Courses are more like channels in YouTube. On them users upload diferent videos. The form where they create the "channel" is based on their profile user where they access on the courses dashboard. It is a bit complex. Of course it would be easier as you said creating a cpt putting user meta values from author. But here it isn't possible 

Comment: I disagree, **it is possible**, don't store the course name in user meta, store it in the course posts title. There are lots of alternatives, such as storing the channel post ID in user meta instead, then displaying its title in your profile editor. That would avoid the need for the SQL query, and completely avoid your problem ( as well as 1 or 2 you haven't realised involving `-2` postfixes and clashing slugs ). You could even search for the channel post that whos author is the current user and render it as an option

Comment: If you stored the ID, then you could even simplify the saving/update code, `wp_insert_post` will update a post if you set the post ID. I also notice you used `$user->course_name`, have you modified the `WP_User` class/table?!?!

Comment: I use custom fields that are added on user profile. Users has access to their profile where they can update their info. I'll try to send the form values directly to the cpt. But, still I have the problem with the url. When they change the title it changes the url. What is ok. But I want to delete the old one. Thank you

Comment: If you did it that way, no new post would be created, and no old post would need to be deleted, the problem you're trying to fix would no longer be there. You've only provided the save code in your question so I cannot formulate an alternative solution for you, you might be using a plugin you've not mentioned to add fields which complicates things due to the unknowns. Can you add the code for displaying the values in the profile edit screen too? Are you using a plugin to add those fields? If so which one?

Comment: Ok,thanks Tom. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be helpful if you could explain why you're generating courses out of edits that a user's doing on his profile. The simplest solution seems to be a frontend form that just allows a user to create new posts or edit existing ones rather than going for this alternative solution where you're using the data from the profile page to create new posts.

---

If you want to stick to the current implementation, I believe it would be useful for you to look into status transitions: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/

Here's some example code that I used to create a post in a the category with the ID 1 (= news) after a custom post type had been created:

```
// Automatically create a news when a wiki post has been published
function nxt_create_news($new_status, $old_status, $nxt_wiki_post) {
    if('publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && $nxt_wiki_post->post_type === 'wiki') {
        $nxt_post_author = $nxt_wiki_post->post_author;
        $nxt_wiki_permalink = get_post_permalink($nxt_wiki_id);
        $nxt_wiki_title = $nxt_wiki_post->post_title;
        $nxt_postarr = array(
            'post_author' => $nxt_post_author,
            'post_content' => 'The wiki entry ' . $nxt_wiki_title . ' has just been published.<br /><br /><a href="' . $nxt_wiki_permalink . '" title="' . $nxt_wiki_title . '">Check out wiki entry</a>.',
            'post_title' => 'The wiki entry ' . $nxt_wiki_title . ' has been published',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_category' => array(1),
        );
        $nxt_post_id = wp_insert_post($nxt_postarr);
        set_post_thumbnail(get_post($nxt_post_id), '1518');
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'nxt_create_news', 10, 3 );
```

---

In your specific case, you can compare parts of the saved posts to the new post that would be created and then prevent the default action from happening (a new post being created) and instead just edit the old post.

The main question would be how would the system know which post someone's trying to edit? I can't really answer that as I couldn't make out why you're using the profile edits to create new posts I'm afraid, but I hope this is helpful regardless. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But will your code not rewrite the url? It seems it stays with the old one...

Comment: My code when the course title is changed it changes the url. That's why it creates a new post and it doesn't update the post. But, in my case this is crucial. That's why when there is a new course (thay just can have one) should delete the old one and stay with the new course title and url

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any of that, and can sidestep the problem completely, and make the code faster and simpler!

This is what we're going to do:

- We're going to use the course post author, not the name, it's more reliable
- We're going to avoid the raw SQL query so we can use caches and use `WP_Query`
- We'll use `wp_insert_post` for both updating and creating the post
- Eliminate a useless `array_map` call
- Actually check if `wp_insert_post` was succesful or not
- We'll apply the WP coding standards to make it easier to read and nicer to work with, e.g. modern PHP arrays `[]` rather than `array()`, strict `in_array` checks, no global variables
- The code that figures out the course ID will be moved to its own function

This way, when the course name changes, the original `course` post has its title and URL updated/changed, rather than creating a brand new `course` that requires cleanup of old courses.

Here's something close to what should work:

```php
function get_course_by_author( $user_id ) : int {
    // if we don't find anything then a value of 0 will create a new post rather than update an existing post.
    $course_id = 0;
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'course',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_author'    => $user_id,
    ];
    $query     = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $course_id = get_the_ID();
            // we only want a single post ID
            break;
        }
        // cleanup after the query
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        // perhaps the course was created before post authors were set? Fall back to looking for the post by its slug/name
        return 0;
    }
    return $course_id;
}

function get_course_by_slug( string $slug ) : int {
    $course_id = 0;
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'course',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_name'      => $slug,
    ];
    ... etc etc see get_course_by_author ...
    return $course_id;
}

function handle_course_post( $user_id = '' ) {
    // First, is this user an instructor?
    $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );
    if ( ! $user || ! in_array( 'instructor', $user->roles, true ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // get the course name
    $course_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'course_name', true );
    if ( empty( $course_name ) {
        error_log( "the user does not have a course_name!" );
    }

    // Then lets find this users course if it exists.
    // if we don't find anything then a value of 0 will create a new post rather than update an existing post.
    $course_id = get_course_by_author( $user_id );
    if ( $course_id === 0 ) {
        // we didn't find a course with that author, try the course name.
        $course_id = get_course_by_slug( $course_name );
    }

    // Finally, save/update the course!
    $content  = 'This is the page for: ';
    $content .= get_user_meta( $user_id, 'description_course', true );
    $args     = [
        'ID'           => $course_id,
        'post_title'   => $course_name,
        'post_name'    => $course_name, // set the slug/permalink
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_type'    => 'course',
    ];
    $post_id  = wp_insert_post( $args );

    // check if we were succesful.
    if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
        // it didn't work!
        error_log( $post_id->get_error_message() );
    } else if ( empty( $post_id ) ) {
        // it didn't work!
        error_log( "post_id is empty/false" );
    }

}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'handle_course_post' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'handle_course_post' );
```

Remember this is untested and will require some understanding, it can't be copy pasted as is ( although if it does work as is then yay! ).

Notice that at the end we check if the call to `wp_insert_post` worked or not. We can't assume it was succesful, what if another user has already chosen that course name? What if the user is no longer an instructor?

Also keep in mind that your existing `course` posts do not have the right author, they will need to be re-saved. Once this is done all cases will be handled. The code above will try to fetch the course post via its slug if it can't find it via the author, allowing a partial migration path.

This does mean your original problem will still happen, but only to users who have never updated their profile, and immediatley change their course name. Those who save their profiles then change the name will be handled, as will all future users.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Have tested and changed a bit trying to figure out how to make it work. When I update the form with new course name it changes the value on user profile. But it doesn't create any new custom post type. And  in consequence it doesn't delete any old post.

Comment: It updates the old post, no new post is created, there is no deletion necessary. The original course is renamed and its URL changed to the new course name/URL

Comment: Have also created directly a course post on add new and it publish it but it doesn't delete the old ones. Nope. it doesn't update posts. It just creates new ones.

Comment: I can't see on the code where it changes the URL.

Comment: By changing the `post_name` the URL is changed, the `post_name` is the posts slug that determines its permalink/URL. WP doesn't store a full URL in the database, but rather it uses the URL to figure out what to load. ***Keep in mind that your old code did not set the post author***, so it won't pick up old course posts, but newly created ones do get picked up. I've adjusted the code to move finding the course into separate functions and made one or two extra comments that should help. I also added basic type hinting to the functions

Comment: Tom. It just updates user profile info. It doesn't create or update posts. I deleted old posts and commented the user role condition. Tested with admin and instructor role. It just updates profile fields. It doesn't create new posts. With my old code it was creating the custom posts

Comment: I don't have enough information to debug, I cannot tell at which point the code fails from your comments. I require debugging information, is there anything in the PHP error log? The example above doesn't attempt to handle when `wp_insert_post` fails, you will need to output the error message in the WP_Error object that was returned ( `$post_id` ) so that we know what the problem is. That it doesn't work on its own isn't enough information. Also as I mentioned this code is untested and isn't a copy paste solution

Comment: There is no error in error_log file. Debug is set to true. I see in users table that the user with who I tested has a post. But there are no posts on the custom post type section. And I'm reading everywhere and just can't figure out what is wrong. It is so frustating...

Comment: the answer will be in the `$post_id` variable, it'll hold an error object that describes what the problem is, we need the error message in that variable

Comment: Well I added your code on single_channel.php whithout the hook to see if it displays something the `echo $post_id`. Of course whithout the add_ action. I put the `echo $post_id` above the // Check if we were succesful and inside the if `(empty ($post_id) || is_wp_error ($post_id))`. Nothing is shown. Didn't put it on funcitons.php because if it doesnt display the post type (channel) How will I see the error??? I'm super confused.... I thought I had it and with this code I feel just lost.

Comment: You can't put filters like this inside theme templates, and that's not how you display the contents of a `WP_Error` object, see here for an example https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/#comment-1973, in the meantime you can use the `error_log` function to log the message to the error log

Comment: I wrote after `//check if we were succesful` and inside `if (empty ($post_id)...`  `global $post_id; if (is_wp_error($post_id)) { global $error; $error = new Wp_Error (); echo $error;` and in `if (empty ($post_id ) || ...`the same. On the form page I added                `<p><?php global $error; echo var_dump($error); ?></p>` . What I get is an empty array `array(0) { }` . So if I did it right it doesnt show anything.

Comment: When I fill the frontend form it updates the fields on the user profile. But it doesn't create the course post type. And if I look how many posts the user has it shows zero. So it is like saving values from form to user metafields works. But from there to create a new post type or (update existing post type) doesn't happen

Comment: It's showing as empty because rather than using the error object, you created a brand new empty error object, so when you dumped it out to the browser there was no error message to see because you never added one. Instead `$post_id` is what you want to work with. `wp_insert_post` either returns the post ID, or it returns an error object, it's that error object that contains the message we want. Otherwise it's like someone handing you the error message and instead of reading it we take a blank page from a notebook then wonder why it's blank.

Comment: `error_log( $post_id->get_error_message() )` will print the error message to the error log

Comment: I'm sorry but I really can't follow you. We are spending a lot of time in comments. I feel sorry for you too. I mean, I've set `wp-config` with all the DEBUGS true. I added the `error_log( $post_id->get_error_message() )` after the `/ /check if we were succesful` and after the `ìf ( empty ($post_id ) || is_wp_error ( ...` I go to `error_log'and it shows nothing. The code looks good but never felt so lost with the comments and trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: As you have updated the code on the answer. Is it right how error_log () is set? I'm testing it and it shows no error so as it doesn't create any post either.

Comment: Found out the problem. When saving the form it updates the meta fields in user profile. But it doesn't create the post. Because this code just works when the user profile is updated not when the form is created or updated.